# What is <Directory> section in apache's <virtualhost>?

Tags: apache-2.2

I am changing few settings in the apache configuration file and I found that in another similar server, it has the following settings:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

within the  tag..

What does this mean exactly? and is this absolutely necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory tab is a way to define security per directory under the virtualhost.
You can find the full documentation on the apache.org site:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory

Comment: alright.. it seems that the path mentioned there seems to refer to documentroot. Is this how it's meant to be or is it a simple coincidence?

Comment: Coincidence, if you keep reading you can see that they describe how to define paths with wildcards etc.

Comment: alright.. in that case do you have any idea why such rules were added to the /var/www/html directory?

Comment: It looks like it's ment to give everyone full permissions on the html directory.